# Direct access to embedded cached HSQLDB server?

Tags: java, hsqldb

I have a process which contains an embedded HSQLDB database.  This database is started with the cached setting:

```
db = new Server();
db.setNoSystemExit(true);
db.setDaemon(true);
db.setDatabaseName(0, "store");
// default to cached or this will turn into an in-memory db by default
db.setDatabasePath(0, "file:" + new File(dataDirectory + "/store/db").getAbsolutePath()
    + ";hsqldb.default_table_type=cached;hsqldb.result_max_memory_rows=" + maxMemoryRows + ";hsqldb.cache_file_scale=" + cacheFileScale);
db.setPort(DefaultEndpoints.getPort(baseport, Ports.STORE_DB_OFFSET));
db.start();  //
```

I have no problem connecting to this database via the normal JDBC connection string:

```
final String connStr = "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + DB_NAME;
```

This works fine.  But I have a series of queries that I am initiating from within the same process as the server.  Is there a way to directly connect to the server without going over a `Socket`?  I'm wondering if I can realize some performance gains this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JDBC URL to connect directly to the database is:

```
"jdbc:hsqldb:file:" + new File(dataDirectory + "/store/db").getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: I can also verify that this works with multiple threads accessing the db and the mvcc mode on.